# mPDF: When I add font into .ttfonts folder then config them. mPDF is display strange text

Tags: php, html, mpdf

I have this problem. I Don't know how to explain.

When I add thai font (TH sarabun) into .ttfonts folder. 
and config in config_fonts.php file
follow this:

```
"sarabun" => array(/* Thai */
        'R' => "THSarabun.ttf",
        'B' => "THSarabun_Bold.ttf",
        'I' => "THSarabun_Italic.ttf",
        'BI' => "THSarabun_Bold_Italic.ttf",        
        'useOTL' => 0xFF,
),

//similar garuda font'
//"garuda" => array(/* Thai */
//      'R' => "Garuda.ttf",
//      'B' => "Garuda-Bold.ttf",
//      'I' => "Garuda-Oblique.ttf",
//      'BI' => "Garuda-BoldOblique.ttf",
//      'useOTL' => 0xFF,
//  ),
```

Then I coding mpdf follow this (I assume my code isn't error.)

```
$this->pdf = new mPDF();
$html = $this->load->view('.........');  
$this->pdf->writeHTML($html);
$this->pdf->Output();
```

Then mPDF displays the square text and text. 
follow this:
[image]

The square text is wrong or bad reading
I want to remove square text or don't want to show or disappear.

How should I solve these problems?

P.S. 
If I remove `'useOTL' => 0xFF` is correct display.But Word wrapping is bad. 
It's more than space when I used justify text. or some line is short. Some line is long.

example: [image]

Comment: Are you sure the font you are using is supporting all the characters you are trying to write?

Comment: I'm sure that my font is support all the characters because each word is  correct display. But square characters or square text is outsider (or supernumerary or Exceeding)